# CSS overlaying centered text with fixed div, links not working

Tags: css, hyperlink, center

Attempting to make links work when pressing a fixed div to lower onto another.

The main bar, illustrated in pink holds the links, and when using the usual methods to overlay a div containing the text onto the bar it stops the links from working due to the full width container div holding the text.

I would like to know if there is a possible route to getting the desired result?!

Heres the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/8upUx/)

The HTML

```
<div class='text-wrapper'>
    <div class='text_in_middle'>
        some text
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class='bar'>
        &nbsp;
        <a href='' >Link 1</a> -
        <a href='' >Link 2</a> -
        <a href='' >Link 3</a> 

    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
 .text_in_middle {
    text-align: center;
}
.bar {
    z-index: 500;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
}
.text-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 2500;
}
```

Comment: how about you increase the z-index to 2600 for .bar ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8upUx/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it has [somewhat limited support](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events), one way to solve this would be to add [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to the fixed element. In doing so, you wouldn't have to change any other CSS/HTML.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FF9Ly/)

```
.text-wrapper {
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 2500;
}
```

Comment: exactly what i needed, even with the limited support, this was the perfect fix. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, why not add the background-colour to `<div class='text-wrapper'></div>`?

You will then also need to change your z-index values so the links show up in front.

```
.text_in_middle {
    text-align: center;
}
.bar {
    z-index: 500;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
}
.text-wrapper {
    background-color: pink;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8upUx/3/)